# How can I prove these triangles are congruent?

Tags: geometry

Are the triangles ABF and AFC congruents? It seems to be congruent but I couldn't prove.

[image]

Comment: Depends.  Is O the center of the circle?  Or just a random point?

Comment: @fleablood O is the center

Comment: Then what do you know about the lines  BO and OC?

Comment: @fleablood I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence):

AF = AF

$\angle$AFB = $\angle$AFC

BF = FC

(to prove BF = FC use [RHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence) congruence on triangles BFO and CFO:

OB = OC

OF = OF

$\angle$OFB = $\angle$OFC

$\therefore$ BF = FC)

Comment: Why does EF=FC?

Comment: No, that is complete!